# Word for a person whose job was replaced by an advance in technology

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

As the title so subtly suggests, I am looking for a word describing someone whose job was replaced or eliminated by advances in technology.

For example:

> Blue-Collar Bill, a `[noun]`, is searching for a new job now.

Maybe a verb/participle implying this would work too:

> Blue-Collar Bill was `[participle]`; he was replaced by a sowing machine.

Or maybe,

> My `[adjective]` friend, Blue-Collar Bill, is going to technical school so that he will not feel obsolete anymore.

Another way to put it is that I am looking for a more concise way to say "made obsolete/displaced/replaced by an advance in technology".

I can add more examples if desired.

Comment: The term for this situation might be 'Structural unemployment'. Not sure what the person wiil be called. ''structurally unemployed person...?''

Comment: what @Nikki said.  maybe a ***victim of structural unemployment***

Comment: @Jim Actually reminds me of 'Mr. Bucket' from Charlie and the Chocolate family:)

Comment: @Nikki, I think you should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Downsized means fired, and very likely due to automation.

Comment: @DopappThe 'Mr. Bucket' one??

Comment: @Nikki, the first one with an up vote.

Comment: @DopappTo narrow down my suggestion, the more apt situation seems to be **technological unemployment**. I'll post an answer after a little more browsing so that it complies with your request.

Comment: How about _obsoleted_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to come up with something more appropriate than obsolete or displaced without using a phrase. The word *superannuated* means exactly what you'd like, but it's not commonly used.

Superannuated Via [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/superannuated)

> Outdated or obsolete through age or new developments: "Superannuated
> computing equipment", "a superannuated hippy"

Via [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?&q=define%20superannuated&forcedict=superannuated)

> Obsolete through age or new technological or intellectual
> developments
>
> Synonyms: old,
> old-fashioned, antiquated, out of date, outmoded, broken-down,
> obsolete, disused, defunct

I'd suggest your displaced as an alternative, or perhaps defunct.

Comment: Oxford and google are, usually, largely identical in meanings. Although two sources are not needed, I would recommend ones with different angles of saying the same thing. It better proves your answer as viable. +1 anyways

Answer (score 0):

'A victim of **technological unemployment...**', is the least apt suggestion I'll give (couldn't find one word, my apologies).

> Technological unemployment is the loss of jobs caused by technological change. Such change typically includes the introduction of labour-saving
>   "mechanical-muscle" machines or more 
>   efficient "mechanical-mind" processes
>   (automation). 
>   **-Just as horses employed as prime movers were gradually made 
>   obsolete by the automobile.
>  
>   -Historical examples include artisan weavers reduced to poverty after the
>    introduction of mechanised looms.
>
>   -A contemporary example of 
>   technological unemployment is the 
>   displacement of retail cashiers by self- service tills.**
>   The 
>   phrase "technological unemployment" was popularised by **John Maynard Keynes** in the 1930s.
>   (Source:Wikipedia)

Dictionary.com also defines it as:
**Noun:** unemployment caused by
 technological changes or new 
methods of production in an
 industry or business.

> Blue-Collar Bill, a [victim of technological unemployment ] , is searching for a new job now.

I didnot answer **structural unemployment** because it has 'not only technological' but a wide-range of factors causing unemployment (now that I see).

> Technological unemployment is a **form of structural unemployment**
>    wherein the structure of the economy 
>   changes with the shifts in demand for 
>   manpower due to the introduction of 
>   new machinery, time-saving technology
>    and improved methods of production.
>   (Source:businessjargons.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can say

> bill was made redundant by the technological advance.

The meaning is more broad than "technological advance" but it still makes sense here.

Bill could also be "made redundant" by a number of other reasons. Maybe he was laid off, his job was outsourced, etc. The term means that his work was no longer necessary.